# If this is not a DIR in my what could it be? Trying to access a file

Tags: directory, filesystems, command-prompt

What could id.json be? I'm trying to access/or inspect the file.

```
 Directory of C:\Users\ssand\.config\solana

02/09/2022  12:42 PM    <DIR>          .
02/09/2022  12:42 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/09/2022  11:05 AM    <DIR>          cli
02/09/2022  12:42 PM               239 id.json
02/09/2022  10:50 AM    <DIR>          install
               1 File(s)            239 bytes
               4 Dir(s)   7,804,948,480 bytes free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a file, not a directory. Files don't have `<DIR>` written near them, but have their size.

From the name, it seems like a `JSON` file. These files can be opened as text.

Comment: Thank you; What would the command be for the terminal to open it? Do you know

Comment: @slim.syd You can use `notepad id.json` to open the file in Windows notepad or `type id.json` to print it in the command line.